# How to exit stopped Python progam in Pygame 'fullscreen' mode?

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I'm developing some Raspberry Pi code - Python in Pygame - and I often want to view it's video-out in fullscreen mode.   But since it's in dev, I often run into code errors that stop the Python program - printing the error-info in the Idle shell.   But in fullscreen mode, even though the program has stopped, I haven't found a way to exit the screen to get back to Idle.

Anybody know a simple way?

I know I could probably be more defensive in catch-exception blocks, but I would think there's some non programatic way to exit after an error-stop.

Comment: I'm not sure if in fullscreen will work `Alt+Tab` which changes active window in Linux. This way you could activate other window - ie. IDLE - and you could kill or close PyGame.

Comment: After receiving any errors, go to Idle and type `pygame.quit()`. Then your window will terminate

Answer (score 2):

It is a nice place to make use of the `try--finally` pattern -

If your code have an `init` function to enter fullscreen, and a `main` to actually run the game, it could go like that:

```
import pygame
...

def init():
   global screen
   screen = pyame.display.set_mode(...)
   ...

def main():
   ...

try:
   init()
   main()
finally:
   pygame.quit()
```